# This iPhone 5s is running iOS 11.0.3 , which may not be supported by this version of Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, ios11

I just updated my phone to 11.0.3
I'm trying to test my app on the phone but its stating :
This iPhone 5s (Model A1457, A1518, A1528, A1530) is running iOS 11.0.3 (15A432), which may not be supported by this version of Xcode.

I checked the app store if there  was a new version of xcode but it turned out that I had the latest one installed

Comment: what is the version of your Xcode?

Comment: Version 8.3.3 (8E3004b)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current version of **Xcode** in AppStore is **9.0.1**. The **Xcode** **8.3.3** does not support **iOS 11.0.3**.

Do not forget to update your macOS to the latest version.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The latest version of XCode is 9.0  and it can be downloaded from MacOS Sierra 10.12.6 up. So you need to updated MacOS first, then download the new XCode 9, then you'll be able to use your phone for debug